# How to externalize configurations for multiple webapps inside a tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running a standalone `tomcat` webserver, with multiple different web applications (`war` files).

Question: I want to externalize some sensitive `application.properties` fields like database accounts, each separated for every application.

I could provide the following property at startup:
`--Dspring.config.additional-location=/etc/java/`

Problem: each webapp would load the same `/etc/java/application-production.properties` file then! So that doesn't help.

Question: how can I separate them by application, so each of the webapps loads it's own additional external file?

Like on the testserver:

```
/etc/java/myapp1/application-test.properties
/etc/java/myapp2/application-test.properties
```

Prod:

```
/etc/java/myapp1/application-production.properties
/etc/java/myapp2/application-production.properties
```

Comment: Are you using maven? You might be able to achieve this using maven profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file that only contains the sensitive data:

`/src/main/resources/config/application-production.properties`

And add a `.gitignore` so that this specific file will not be commited for version control.

Answer (score 1):

one way to go is, you create key-value files, like `test1.env, test2.env...`. The content would be:

```
DB_URL=test1DB
DB_USR=hi
DB_PWD=pwd
...
```

In your `application.properties` you can use placeholder like `db.url=${DB_URL}`

When you start your application, using a start (shell) script, `export` the variables in *.env, and source the given `env` file, so that the right values can be filled in application.properties.